# Lotus Notes: Losing data when export view data to a csv file

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus

I have a view in Lotus Notes 8.5 that I want to export the data to a csv file.
There are these kind of fields that are list.
Say I have a field called "editors".It has multiple editors for one document.
When I export the data to a csv file, the field is "frank, john, Tom". It is comma separated.
But I found that sometimes, it is losing data. Sometimes I only got "frank, john". "Tom" is lost.

Comment: How are you doing the export? Are you 100% sure that the list is stored properly as multi-values? (I.e., have you examined the field data in the Document Properties dialog or in NotesPeek to see whether it might actually be stored as "frank, john" : "Tom"?)

Comment: I am exporting using Files/Export. Not using any scripts or code to do so. For the field, the Data Type is Text List. When I examine the data in Documents Properties dialog. It is always the right data. "Frank""john""Tom".

Comment: Okay. That sounds strange. Perhaps a bug in the export facility. You may have to follow Karl-Henry's advice and write code to work around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have had the same thing happen to me.... losing data.  I found that in some of the fields there were commas included in the field values and this is how the data did not completely export.

I ended up writing an agent with Lotusscript and exported the data in that manner.

Comment: You are right. It only happens to Data Type is Text List. Which means that in the view, the field has values contains comma. Do you have more information about your Lotusscript agent?

Comment: It's pretty easy to write a CSV export agent in Lotusscript, I think any Notes developer been writing at least one... :-)
You could take a look at the code on my blog that I linked to in my answer, I am sure that will help you, it even specifically address multi-value fields.

Comment: Yep. I am sure that should be easy. Actually I am not a Notes Developer.  I have tried your code in your blog. It actually took quite long for a view that has about 24 documents and later some error comes out. Before the error, the Notes Designer and Client all frozed. Is it because I am doing it in the wrong way.I have almost 29k documents to export.

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something wrong in your code, could you either post it or mail it to me? texasswede (at) gmail.com and I will take a look at it.

Comment: I have written my own code to do the export. But your Blog helps a lot. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please show your code for exporting the view to CSV.
Are you looping through the NotesView, opening each document and using the GetItemValues method to get the values, or are you looping through a NotesViewEntryCollection, getting each NotesViewEntry and then using the ColumnValues property to get the visible values in the view?

I suspect that your problem is that you are not treating the values you get back as arrays, but instead only read the first value of the array. If you could post your code, it would help.

You could take a look at some code I posted on my blog a while back, perhaps that can help you:
http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

Comment: You may also want to select a "real" name, an avatar and update your profile to tell more about yourself. It is always nice to know who I am talking to/helping.

Comment: I am not writing any code to do the export. All I am doing to do use the Menu,  File/Export, then the view is exported to a csv file.

Comment: Then this would really belong on the Super User forums, not here where programming is discussed.
The File/Export functionality that you use is very simple, if you want any control of the output, or have any issues, you should write Lotusscript code to handle it. It's not very complicated, and most/all of the code is in my link above.

And thanks you for adding your real name to your profile.